# PHP - How to find a between value from first array in second array

Tags: php, arrays

In two different arrays, I have to find between value of each array1 value.

```
$array1 = array(8,15,26);
$arrayBetween = array ("zero" => 0, "one"=>10,"two" =>20, "three" =>30);
```

Example: `8 is between zero and one.`

I didn't find any function that can help me. I've tried with `array_filter` or `range` but I can't solve it.

Comment: No such function that I can think of, that's an extremely specialized requirement. You'll likely need to write your own loop to do it.

Comment: Please add expected output.  Also, is `$arrayBetween` always going to go in ascending order, or could the it be something like `$arrayBetween = array ("one"=>10, "zero" => 0, "three" =>30, "two" =>20);`?

Answer (score 0):

You can write it yourself with a simple loop :

```
$array1 = array(-1,8,15,26,47);
$arrayBetween = array ("zero" => 0, "one"=>10,"two" =>20, "three" =>30);

foreach($array1 as $value)
{
    // special cases if value is outside arrayBetween bounds
    if($value < min($arrayBetween))
        echo "$value is before " . array_keys($arrayBetween)[0] . PHP_EOL ;
    elseif($value > max($arrayBetween))
    {
        $keys = array_keys($arrayBetween) ;
        echo "$value if after " . end($keys) . PHP_EOL ;
    }
    else
    {
        $prevKey = null ; // store the previous key at each try
        foreach($arrayBetween as $key => $nb)
        {
            if($nb > $value) // we found the first key that has value > current number
            {
                echo "$value is between $prevKey and $key ". PHP_EOL ;
                break; // interval found, can stop the search
            }

            $prevKey = $key ; // save current key to display it if next element is > $value
        }
    }
}
```

Output :

> -1 is before zero
>
> 8 is between zero and one
>
> 15 is between one and two
>
> 26 is between two and three
>
> 47 if after three